# How to validate the JSON Request in camel rest

Tags: rest, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I need to validate incoming request to the camel rest service based on some schema. for example.

In request as given below

```
{
 "routeId" : "fileBatchRoute",
 "action" : "start",
 "sourceLocation" : "sourceDirectory",
 "destinationLocation" : "destinationDirectory"
}
```

Above request should be validated based on below conditions 
1. It must contain action element and format should be above.
2. RouteId should be present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [json-validator](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-json-validator/src/main/docs/json-validator-component.adoc) component.
With schema generation can help you tool [JSONschema.net](https://www.jsonschema.net/).

---

With your requirements (routeId is required, action is required and is one of "start", "stop", "suspend", "resume") could schema be something like:

**routeSchema.json:**

```json
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "routeId",
    "action"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "routeId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "action": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "start",
        "stop",
        "suspend",
        "resume"
      ]
    },
    "sourceLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "destinationLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

**Route definition:**

```java
.to("json-validator:routeSchema.json")
```

Comment: only supports version 4 of the JSON schema unfortunately